# Reading NFC data

Tags: nfc, rfid

As part of my university project I am trying to read NFC data (13.56MHz) at a longer range (~60 cm). I have already developed code that reads data from the card at close proximity, using libnfc and a standard USB based NFC reader.

I am facing the challenge to read data from distance. All the information I have seen out there seems to be a few years old with unsupported hardware.

My initial thoughts were to try to find a NFC reader that I could just plugged a bigger antenna, as you can do with 802.11 wireless technology...

I would appreciate some tips on how to achieve my goal, what type of hardware would I need? And could I still use libnfc and my code?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The current state of the NFV standard relates to the RFID standard ISO14443, which is a shortrange system. The NFC forum works on adding ISO15693 to the NFC standard, which allows longrange applications. Some NFC devices do support ISO15693 already.

With a proper longrange reader and a large antenna, 60cm with ISO15693 tags is possible.

However, aside of the type of RFID used in the tags, there is also the issue of the RF power for the reader antenna. A mobile device, like a phone, does not have enough energy to power a longrange antenna to read over 60cm distance.